# How to enable a specific system audit policy in PowerShell in Windows 11?

Tags: powershell, audit, windows-11, auditing

There doesn't seem to be a native PowerShell way to do this.

I want to enable this audit

[image]

I'm using PowerShell and sadly there is no auto-complete to help with it.
I've been searching and reading [Auditpol documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/auditpol-set) but can't figure out why i can't set this.

first I used this to get all the category and sub-category GUIDs

```
auditpol /list /subcategory:* /r
```

then tried this:

```
auditpol /set /category:{6997984A-797A-11D9-BED3-505054503030} /subcategory:{0CCE9225-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030} /failure:enable /success:enable
```

but it fails.

also tried this

```
auditpol /set /category:Object Access,{6997984A-797A-11D9-BED3-505054503030} /subcategory:{0CCE9225-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030} /failure:enable /success:enable
```

still fails.

so what is the correct syntax exactly? I have the names, I have the GUIDs, don't know why it's not working.

also how does the GUI work exactly? if i enable it successfully from command line, should I restart the system to see the effect in GUI? should I close and reopen it?

Oh and I want to set it for the entire system, not for a specific user.

Comment: No active directory?

Comment: Curly braces `{}` have special meaning in PowerShell.  Try surrounding with quotes (e.g., `auditpol /set /category:"{6997984A-797A-11D9-BED3-505054503030}" /subcategory:"{0CCE9225-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030}" /failure:enable /success:enable`) or use cmd.exe instead.  You may also escape the braces by placing a grave accent character (aka backtick) before them.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you very much, that worked, I had to remove the `category` and only keep the `subcategory` in order to only activate that specific audit and not all of the subcategories of `object access`.  and the GUI doesn't reflect the changes I make using command line, at least not until I restart which I haven't tried yet.

 
js2010, there is no active directory, just my own personal system.